# Using jquery form validation but modal still pops up even when invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-modal

I am using jquery's form validation plugin which is highly useful. But how do I prevent the modal from opening on submit?

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

$().ready(function() {
$("#dzCalculator").validate({
rules: {
    
initialVelocity: "required",
yellowPhase: "required",
number: true,
digits: true,
range: [0.01, 1000],
maxlength: 6
},

messages: {
initialVelocity: "Please provide an initial velocity as a number between 1 and 1000 and select units",
yellowPhase: "Please provide the time the traffic light remains yellow, typically between 4 and 7 seconds"

}
});
});
```

Here is an example of the code I use, what code do I use to prevent the submit button from opening the modal and displaying the data they have submitted? I am using Bootstrap modals.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of this code. Its hard to tell what wrong with peice of code only.

Comment: Especially since your problem seems to be some modal opening when it shouldnt but the code that opens the modal is missing

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to see the html for the button push that opens the modal? There's a preventDefault code that I just don't know how to apply here on a false validation.